# How to set the AudioStreamPlayer to switch between tracks

Tags: audio, music, godot

**Conditional Music Playback**

What's important here is that I know how to switch the track that's being played back to another if some condition is met in the scene. If possible I also want to know where to store the other tracks.

I looked into the documentation and have yet to find a solution that allows me to for example:

- set the new track's file path and play it or...
- store the track names in maybe an array and set them for playback in the script. (still requires something to change the currently playing track)

How do I switch the tracks based on any condition?

Answer (score 0):

**Set_stream(track)**

where track is the audiostream object. It can be accessed by exporting the value with

```
export (AudioStream) var track
```

And then selecting the track in the inspector.

Comment: If this solved your problem, remember to click the checkmark to the left to mark the answer as "Accepted".